# Ansible + AWS EC2 Plugin + username + ssh key on the dynamic inventory file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I'm using the aws_ec2 plugin to get my inventory on AWS but I need some help.

I want to set the 'ansible_user' and 'ansible_ssh_private_key_file' on the dynamic inventory file but I cant get it work. ¿Is this possible? So I don't need to set the '--private-key' and '-u' options on the command line.

This is my current aws_ec2.yaml:

```
---
plugin: aws_ec2
aws_access_key: 123
aws_secret_key: 345
filters:
  tag:Cliente: CustName
  instance-state-name : running
```

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create and load dynamic variables for each Ansible host group. You need to create appropriate files on your inventory directory. For example: Say you have configured your `ansible.cfg` file with the `inventory` key pointing to the relative path `./inventory`. This tells Ansible that it should look inside a file called `./inventory` or a series of files inside the `./inventory` folder for the host group's information.

You tell Ansible to load different variables for each group just by following the appropriate convention for the folder structure:

- `./inventory/group_vars`: will hold group variables.
- `./inventory/host_vars`: will hold host variables.

Ansible will use the file's name inside each of these folders to reference the appropriate `group` or `host`. You can also use sub-directories with the group's name if you want to use multiple files to hold all the variables.

> It's important that your `aws_ec2.yml` file be located inside the `./inventory` directory.

For example: if you wanted to store the appropriate `user` and `key` configuration to access EC2 instances tagged with the `Project` tag set to `stackoverflow`, you would need to create a directory at `./inventory/group_vars/tag_Project_stackoverflow` with a variables file like the following:

```yaml
ansible_user: ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

> The EC2 dynamic inventory module can create dynamic groups from the configuration of your EC2 instances. Check its [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html) to see how to configure it.

You can even create these files dynamically using tasks. Here I create a new ec2 key, store it locally, and create the necessary folder structure to hold the connection information:

```yaml
- name: Create a new EC2 key
  amazon.aws.ec2_key:
    name: "{{ ec2_key_name }}"
  register: ec2_key_output

- name: Save private key
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: "{{ ec2_key_output.key.private_key }}"
    dest: "{{ ec2_key_path }}"
    mode: 0600
  when: ec2_key_output.changed == True

- name: Create the group_vars folder
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: ./inventory/group_vars
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Create the group_vars configuration file
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: |
      ansible_user: "{{ ec2_user }}"
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ec2_key_path }}"
    dest: ./inventory/group_vars/tag_Project_stackoverflow
```

Please check out [Ansible's documentation regarding inventory management](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) for more information.

Comment: Great! Let me try and I'll come back with you to share the results.